# creating a spy function using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a spy function that will do this.

```
const func1 = function (x, y) {return x + y};
const func2 = spy(func1);
func2(2, 5) // => 7
func2(4, 5) // => 9
func2.calls() // => 2
func2.args() // => [[2, 5], [4, 5]]
```

I have created this function but I can seem to get the calls and args

```js
function spy(func) {
  let count = 0;
  let allArgs = [];
    function ispy() {
        let args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        spy.calls = function() {
           return count++;
        }
        spy.args = function() {
          return allArgs.push(args2)
        }
        func.apply(this, args2);
    }
    
    return spy;
}

const func1 = function (x, y) {return x + y};
const func2 = spy(func1);
console.log(func2(2, 5)) 
console.log(func2.calls())
console.log(func2.args())
```

Please help me fix it and let me know what am I missing?

Comment: The variables inside the spy method are scoped too low.  The count is created, initialized, and destroyed every invocation.

Comment: Actually, did you make a mistake in returning `spy` and not `ispy`?

Comment: Also why are `calls()` and `args()` adjusting the record keeping variables, rather than just reporting them?

Comment: and you add functions to `spy` in a call of `ispy()` and increment `count` in call of `calls` instead of call of `ispy` and many other mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

You add functions to spy in a call of ispy() and increment count in call of calls instead of call of ispy, you don't return result of func, you assign `calls` and `args` functions in every call to `ispy` and many other mistakes

```js
function spy(func) {
  let count = 0;
  let allArgs = [];
  function ispy(...args) {
      count++;
      allArgs.push(args);
      return func.apply(this, args);
  }

  ispy.calls = function() {
     return count;
  }
  ispy.args = function() {
    return allArgs;
  }
    
  return ispy;
}

const func1 = function (x, y) {return x + y};
const func2 = spy(func1);
console.log(func2(2, 5));
console.log(func2(4, 5));
console.log(func2.calls())
console.log(func2.args())
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things,
You need to keep track of count and allArgs for every invocation of the spy call.
You need to return the result of the spied upon function from spy.

```js
function spy(func) {
  let count = 0;
  let allArgs = [];
  function spy() {
      // increment count on every invocation
      count++;
      let args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      // shove arguments onto the allArgs array.
      allArgs.push(args2);
      spy.calls = function() {
         return count;
      }
      spy.args = function() {
        return allArgs;
      }
      
      //return the result;
      return func.apply(this, args2);
  }
    
    return spy;
}

const func1 = function (x, y) {return x + y};
const func2 = spy(func1);
console.log(func2(2, 5)) 
console.log(func2.calls())
console.log(func2.args())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the arguments directly with rest parameters and return in the function only the value of the variables. The assignemnt should happen outside of the function, because if not it would require a call of `func2` first.

Each call of `ispy` should be counted and the arguments should be added to.

```js
function spy(func) {
    function ispy(...args) {
        count++;
        allArgs.push(args);
        return func.apply(this, args);
    }

    let count = 0;
    let allArgs = [];
    ispy.calls = () => count;
    ispy.args = () => allArgs;

    return ispy;
}

const func1 = function (x, y) {return x + y};
const func2 = spy(func1);

console.log(func2.calls())
console.log(func2(2, 5)) 
console.log(func2.calls())
console.log(func2.args())
```